# can't get iptables to handle more than 1.5 million nat sessions

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I am trying to see how many NAT sessions I can handle in a single linux machine using iptables. I am testing it using a large number of udp packets but I can't seem to pass 1.5 million. I set net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max to 4194304 and /sys/module/nf_conntrack/parameters/hashsize to the same value. is there any other config I can change to make it support more sessions?

Comment: How many remote hosts are you connecting to?

Comment: currently only 1 for the test, production setup should have a lot more. why does it matter?

Comment: 1.5 million packets over what time interval?  How many connections according to `conntrack --count`  ?